# Tagged Type (@@) Comparison in Scalaz

Tags: scala, tags, scalaz

While playing with `Scalaz.Tag`, I found that an weird comparison result.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, Tags._, syntax.tag._

test("Creating Tagged type") {
  sealed trait USD
  sealed trait EUR
  def USD[A](amount: A): A @@ USD = Tag[A, USD](amount)
  def EUR[A](amount: A): A @@ EUR = Tag[A, EUR](amount)

  val oneUSD = USD(1)
  2 * oneUSD.unwrap shouldBe 2

  def convertUSDtoEUR[A](usd: A @@ USD, rate: A)
                        (implicit M: Monoid[A @@ Multiplication]): A @@ EUR =
    EUR((Multiplication(usd.unwrap) |+| Multiplication(rate)).unwrap)

  convertUSDtoEUR(USD(1), 2) === EUR(2) // true
  convertUSDtoEUR(USD(1), 2) === USD(2) // true

  convertUSDtoEUR(USD(1), 2) shouldBe EUR(2) // true
  convertUSDtoEUR(USD(1), 2) shouldBe USD(2) // true
}
```

I would like to distinguish different sealed traits. Is this intended behavior of `scalaz.Tag` or am i missing something?

---

Updated

I implemented `=:=` as I can't use *scalaz* `===` inside `org.scalatest.FunSuite` due to `org.scalactic.TripleEqualSupport`

```
trait FunTestSuite
  extends FunSuite
  with Matchers
  with BeforeAndAfterEach
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with TestImplicits

trait TestImplicits {
  final case class StrictEqualOps[A](val a: A) {
    def =:=(aa: A) = assert(a == aa)
    def =/=(aa: A) = assert(!(a == aa))
  }

  implicit def toStrictEqualOps[A](a: A) = StrictEqualOps(a)
}

// spec
convertUSDtoEUR(USD(1), 2) =:= EUR(2)
convertUSDtoEUR(USD(1), 2) =:= EUR(3) // will fail
convertUSDtoEUR(USD(1), 2) =:= USD(3) // compile error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `===` and `shouldBe` from scalatest. They only check the runtime value, not the types (they delegate to `==`). If you want to distinguish the type, you'll have to use `===` from scalaz.

Comment: Thanks! @Alvaro Carrasco